# how to substract two column values and show in another column in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

in my code i want to substract column Amount And cost value and show it on profit column.

this is my code...

```
package my.bill;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax .swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class bill extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form bill
     */
    Object[][] data=null;
    String[] columnNames = new String[2];

   /*static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
   //static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "root";*/



    public bill() {
        initComponents();
        CurrentDate();

           }

    public void CurrentDate(){
    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Date.setText(day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Date = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        netprofit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        netsum = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        save = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Date");

        Date.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"", null, null, null, null, null},
                {"", null, null, null, "", null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "JNo", "Item", "Amount", "cost", "Profit", "P"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jTable1.setRowHeight(20);
        jTable1.setRowMargin(2);
        jTable1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTable1.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                jTable1InputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Job No");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Item");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("Billed Amount");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setHeaderValue("Parts cost");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setHeaderValue("Net Profit");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setHeaderValue("Percentage");
        }

        netprofit.setText("Total Profit");
        netprofit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                netprofitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        save.setText("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(114, 114, 114)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(350, 350, 350)
                        .addComponent(netprofit)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(netsum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(221, 221, 221)
                        .addComponent(save)))
                .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(netprofit)
                    .addComponent(netsum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(save)
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        Date.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("date");
        save.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("save");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    private void DateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                    

    private void netprofitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                         

    private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        Connection conn = null;

   Statement stmt = null;

        int count=jTable1.getRowCount();
        int col=jTable1.getColumnCount();
       String jobno[] =new String[count]; // name is array and index 4 means no. of row 
        String item[]=new String[count]; 
        String bill[] =new String[count]; // name is array and index 4 means no. of row 
         String part[]=new  String[count]; 
       String profit[] =new  String[count]; // name is array and index 4 means no. of row 
       String percent[]=new  String[count]; 

       for(int i=0;i<=count;i++) 
 {
     for(int j=0;j<=col;j++)
     {
 no[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString(); // it get value from 0 row and 0 column
it[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
 amount[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
 p[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
 cost[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
s[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();


        try{

            String sql="INSERT INTO m (no,it,amount,cost,sell,p,date) VALUES('"+no[i]+"','"+it[i]+"','"+amount[i]+"','"+p[i]+"','"+cost[i]+"','"+s[i]+"','"+Date.getText()+"')";
          //  stmt.execute(sql);
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //stmt.execute(sql);
            /*PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, "");
            ps.setString(2, "");
            ps.setString(3, "");
            ps.setString(4, "");
            ps.setString(5, "");
            ps.setString(6, "");
            ps.setString(7,Date.getText());
            ps.execute();*/

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"saved");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
 }
    }                                    

    private void jTable1InputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

         Connection conn = null;

   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       //Class.forName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb", "root", "root");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();


   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
     // se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
     // e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   //System.out.println("Goodbye!");

        //int r=jTable1.selectedrow;
        //jTable1.getValue(3,3);
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new bill().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField Date;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JButton netprofit;
    private javax.swing.JTextField netsum;
    private javax.swing.JButton save;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I want to know how to substract two column values show in another column automatically?

Comment: I have removed the JDBC, mysql and sql tags as the question seems to be purely about swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to either use a `AbstractTableModel` or override the functionality of the `DefaultTableModel`

In either case, there are (at least) two ways you can do this...

### You Could...

Override the `getValueAt` method and when asked for the value for the specified column, calculate the amount to return the result...

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Object value = null;
    switch (col) {
        case 4:
            double amount = (Double)getValueAt(row, 2);
            double cost = (Double)getValueAt(row, 3);
            value = cost - amount;
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I'm making assumptions here to demonstrate the point.  If you're using `DefaultTableModel`, you can simply call `super.getValueAt(row, col)` to get the values for the other cells automatically...

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Object value = null;
    switch (col) {
        case 4:
            double amount = (Double)getValueAt(row, 2);
            double cost = (Double)getValueAt(row, 3);
            value = cost - amount;
            break;
        default:
            value = super.getValueAt(row, col);
    }
    return value;
}
```

This is really good if the data is not editable (mostly static) and row data comes completed, otherwise ...

### You Could...

Override the `setValueAt` method at modify the profit value accordingly...

```
public void setValueAt(int row, int col, Object value) {
    if (col != 4) {
        super.setValueAt(row, col, value);
        if (col == 2 || col == 3) {
            double amount = (Double)getValueAt(row, 2);
            double cost = (Double)getValueAt(row, 3);
            setValueAt(row, 4, amount - cost);
        }
    }
}
```

This is better if the data is not static and the user is entering it directly into the table...

## Disclaimer

I've made assumptions about the data types for simplicity, you may need to convert the data to an appropriate format for the calculations

**Updated with simple example**

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
        new String[]{"JNo", "Item", "Amount", "cost", "Profit", "P"}, 0) {
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Object value = null;
        switch (col) {
            case 4:
                double amount = (Double) getValueAt(row, 2);
                double cost = (Double) getValueAt(row, 3);
                value = cost - amount;
                break;
            default:
                value = super.getValueAt(row, col);
        }
        return value;
    }
};
```

### Proof of concept

This is a **Proof of concept** only, do not copy and paste this into your code and expect it to magically work, you are going to have to modify it to meet your needs...

[image: AutoTable]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class AutoSumming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoSumming();
    }

    public AutoSumming() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                                new String[]{"Amount", "Cost", "Profit"},
                                10) {
                                    @Override
                                    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                                        Object value = null;
                                        switch (col) {
                                            case 2:
                                                double amount = getAmountForRow(row);
                                                double cost = getCostForRow(row);
                                                value = cost - amount;
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                value = super.getValueAt(row, col);
                                        }
                                        return value;
                                    }

                                    protected double getAmountForRow(int row) {
                                        return getNumberForRow(row, 0);
                                    }

                                    protected double getCostForRow(int row) {
                                        return getNumberForRow(row, 1);
                                    }

                                    protected double getNumberForRow(int row, int col) {
                                        double number = 0;
                                        Object value = getValueAt(row, col);
                                        if (value != null && value instanceof Number) {
                                            number = ((Number) value).doubleValue();
                                        }
                                        return number;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
                                        if (column != 2) {
                                            if (aValue instanceof Number) {
                                                super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
                                                if (column == 0 || column == 1) {
                                                    fireTableCellUpdated(row, 2);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                                        return Double.class;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                        return column != 2;
                                    }

                                };

                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Take a closer look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a better understanding of how this example works

Comment: in your code it cannot identify the DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
        new String[]{"JNo", "Item", "Amount", "cost", "Profit", "P"}, 0) {

Comment: You need to add an import statement for the DefaultTableModel

Comment: please tell the import statement is import javax.swing.table.*

Comment: how to show the substract value on profit column automatically

Comment: any mathematical operations are the job for SQL interpreter (correct, logical, faster, etc), probably required, miss there getColumnClass

Comment: @mKorbel It's contextual, if the data is not been modified, then yes, absolutly. If the data needs to changed on the UI, then it's faster to do the calculation in on the client then do an insert/update and retrival

Comment: @user3751867 I appreciate that you're first language isn't English, but I am not your code monkey nor are we (StackOverFlow) and code factory, you need to be prepared to take concepts and apply them to your particular situation, there is no magic "band-aid" solution that works for everything.  I have provided a *proof of concept** to demonstrate how the concept can work, you are going to have to understand and modify it to fit your needs.